# file input using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use bootstrap file input to browse a file. I am getting 3 action buttons when I use this
`<input id="myName" type="file" name="myName" class="file" />`

and have the following line in initialization

```
$("#myName").fileinput({ showUpload: false, showRemove: false })
```

But still I see there action buttons "Remove", "Upload" and "Browse". I would like to see only "Browse". I don´t want to change css file. Is there any way to do it in html or js?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput#usage) try using quotes around the options.

For example:

`$("#myName").fileinput({'showUpload':false, 'showRemove':false});`

Comment: thanks, Using quotes also did not help. I debugged the code and call is going to fileinput.js file but  the returned object is not having these options. They have default options

Answer (score 1):

As described by others yes... you need to set the `showUpload` and `showRemove` properties. You can use HTML 5 data attributes to initialize this as shown in [third example on the basic usage section of the demo site](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#basic-usage) - OR - you can directly use javascript to initialize as you have done.

However do not do both. The issue is you have the markup `<input id="myName" type="file" name="myName" class="file" />` which has a `class = file`, which means the plugin will automatically intialize the plugin which is resulting in your JS init code not being processed.

Note that as highlighted in document and in [the first example on basic usage](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#basic-usage) the plugin automatically initializes the file input plugin if you have `input type = file` and `class = file`.

So you must just do the following if you are using javascript to initialize. First remove the `class = file` from your markup:

```
<input id="myName" type="file" name="myName"/>
```

Next initialize the plugin (typically on document ready) and it should work.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("#myName").fileinput({ showUpload: false, showRemove: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way which worked for me is to have those settings false in initialization.

```
<input id="myName" type="file" class="file" data-show-upload="false" data-show-remove="false">
```